# _tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable

Tags: python, tkinter, юнит-тесты

Тесты запускались хорошо,пока я не залил программу на гитхаб,и github actions ,никак не хочет пропускать тесты,из за этой ошибки.Возможно вся проблема в интерпретаторе или в самом файле .yml,но я совершенно не имею понятия как это исправить,

```
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.6/x64/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2270, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

```
root = Tk()
top = Toplevel() 
top.geometry("600x400")
top.title("Клавиатурный тренажер")  
var = IntVar()
Radiobutton(top, text='Легкая', variable=var, value=0).pack()
Radiobutton(top, text='Нормальная', variable=var, value=1).pack()
Radiobutton(top, text='Сложная', variable=var, value=2).pack()
button1 = Button(top, text="Играть", command=lambda: command()).pack()
button2 = Button(top, text="Выйти", command=lambda: command2()).pack()
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("images.jpg"))
panel = Label(top, image=img)
panel.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand="yes")
label5 = Label(top, text="Топ времени игроков:", justify=LEFT, font='Times 10')
label5.place(relx=.1, rely=.1)
label2 = Label(top, text=list_pip(1), justify=LEFT, font='Times 10')
label2.place(relx=.1, rely=.2)
label3 = Label(top, text=list_pip(3), justify=LEFT, font='Times 10')
label3.place(relx=.1, rely=.3)
label4 = Label(top, text=list_pip(5), justify=LEFT, font='Times 10')
label4.place(relx=.1, rely=.4)


def start_app():
    root.withdraw() 
    return root
def command2():
    top.destroy() 
    root.destroy()
    sys.exit()
def command():

    with open("words.txt", "r"):
        test_words1 = src.difficulty.get_words(var.get() + 3)
        app2 = src.difficulty.dif(test_words1)
        app2.mainloop()
    return True
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = start_app()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: github actions запускаются в окружении без графики, экрана физически нет, переменная окружения $DISPLAY не инициализирована, поэтому tkinter не может стартовать. Для тестов возможно придется заменять Tk и прочие объекты на какой-то mock объект.

Comment: P.S. можно запускать на windows-latest вместо ubuntu-latest, тогда проблем с $DISPLAY не будет